# How to change parameters without stopping the program

Tags: python-2.7, input

Suppose I write a program like this.

```
# run the program until the user gives a "stop" input
usrinpt=""`
n=1
while usrinpt!="stop":
    n+=1
    ---- do-something -----
    ---- do-something -----
    ---- do-something -----
print n # print the number of loops it has gone through.
```

Now program will run until I manually change the parameter `usrinpt` to "stop". But using raw_input will stop the simulation at every step which is not what I want.

So, is there a way to change the `usrinpt` without stopting the simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more involved solution using a thread:

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility

import sys
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    input = raw_input

def do_something():
    # doing the work
    sleep(1)

usrinpt = ''

def main():
    n = 1
    while usrinpt != 'stop':
        n += 1
        do_something()
    print('\nnumber of loops', n)

thread = Thread(target=main)
thread.start()

while True:
    print('Enter "stop" to terminate program')
    usrinpt = input().strip().lower()
    if usrinpt == 'stop':
        break

thread.join()
```

Sample program run:

```
python stop.py 
Enter "stop" to terminate program
hello
Enter "stop" to terminate program
stop

number of loops 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception:

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility

n = 1
try:
   while True:
       n += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nnumber of loops', n)
```

When the user types `<CTRL>-<C>` the program prints the number of iterations and continues.

Comment: this would certainly work but is there a way to accomplish this without using interrupts